# Android Chrome Inspect Devices Blank Screen

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, inspect

I'm dealing with a problem since a few days. In normally Chrome Inspect property was working properly but suddenly that broke down. I didn't understand why happened. I'm seeing devices in page. When I clicked to inspect, It opens blank page. I uninstalled and reinstalled chrome but it doesn't work. If you have any idea about this situation, could you help me please?

[image: chrome://inspect/#devices]

[image: blank page]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in the latest Chrome version, try to downgrade to an older version of Chrome.
Here is how can you downgrade Chrome version:
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7125792?hl=en

EDIT:
Use Microsoft Edge browser: edge://inspect/#devices - it's work fine for me.